# How to Render Django Forms.TimeField in 12h Format in Template?

Tags: javascript, python, django, forms, timepicker

I have a Django form that I use to create and update model data. When I create new record, everything works as I simply enter 6:30 pm through my `timepicker`. However when I'm editing the current record, Django is by default displaying the initial time in 24h format such as 18:30:00 and my `timepicker` is expecting 12h format value.

How can I tell Django to output the database value in 12h AM/PM format in my template?

This is the time field in my Django Form

```
self.fields['starttime'] = forms.TimeField(
                            required=True,
                            label='Start Time',
                            input_formats=['%I:%M %p'])
```

In my template I'm using `{{ form.starttime }}` to render the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the format of the `TimeInput` widget manually:

```
self.fields['starttime'] = forms.TimeField(
                            required=True,
                            label='Start Time',
                            input_formats=['%I:%M %p'],
                            widget=forms.TimeInput(format='%I:%M %p'))
```